# How to fix broken libc6 dependencies

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates, dependencies

I am currently on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

When I run sudo apt-get upgrade I receive the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcrypt1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.25) but it is not installed
 libgcc-s1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I attempt apt --fix-broken install and also manually installing  libc6 I receive the following error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I followed the steps I found on this website for that error message:

https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/

None of these steps resolved my issue. Is there anyway to fix these broken package dependencies? Thank you in advance for any assistance.

EDIT: Adding the following requested outputs.

sudo apt update:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                   
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                    
Fetched 108 kB in 11s (10.2 kB/s)                                                                                                  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

apt policy libcrypt1:

```
libcrypt1:
  Installed: 1:4.4.27-1
  Candidate: 1:4.4.27-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.4.27-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

apt policy libgcc-s1:

```
libgcc-s1:
  Installed: 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04
  Candidate: 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04
  Version table:
 *** 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12-20220319-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

apt policy libc6:

```
libc6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.35-0ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
     2.35-0ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.35-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

dpkg -l libc6:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
in  libc6:amd64    <none>       amd64        (no description available)
```

sudo apt install libc6:i386:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcrypt1:i386 (>= 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libidn2-0:i386 (>= 2.0.5~) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libnss-nis:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libnss-nisplus:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libcrypt1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc-s1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.35) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:

```
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'libcrypt1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'libgcc-s1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gun/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Do you have both the amd and 32 bit libc6 packages? Check with dpkg -l libc6

Comment: I added the output to the original comment. It does not appear I have the 32 bit package.

Comment: Unless your system is based on an alternative C implementation like musl, it's hard to see how it can function at all if the libraries provided by the libc6 package were missing - perhaps the package has somehow become marked as not installed in the database, but its files are still there? Does `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` exist for example, and if so, what does `dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` report?

Comment: @steeldriver I don't believe I have any kind of special implementation. I use Grub to dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04. That file does exist. I posted the output in the original post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @karel unfortunately none of those corrected the issue either. Most of those commands I had already tried.

Comment: Try the path /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu   instead of /lib/x86_64-linux-gun on that last dpkg command

Comment: @ubfan1 that was just a typo in the post. Same output.

Answer (score 2):

My solution ended up being to clean install Ubuntu 23.04. At this point it was much more efficient. I have Windows, Ubuntu, and my data all on separate drives, so nothing important is lost and setting Ubuntu up is fast and easy.